# Insert to Oracle Database always creates new Index ID and doesn't take the old one

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle

I am currently trying to insert a DataRow into an Oracle SQL Database. The entry gets inserted into the Database but always gets a new ID. I am providing an ID in the Insert Command but it always uses an auto increment and doesn't let me insert my ID.

What can I do?

Comment: It has a trigger doing that which you or your dba presumably added.

Comment: Or, if you're on 12c, the column might have been created as an *identity* column which auto increments.

Comment: Is there any way I can skip the trigger to insert my own ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions to your problem.

1. Set column as NOT to be "Identity" column. This will take care of
   your issue without any hassle.
2. If you must keep that column as "Identity" column, set "Generated"
   property to "By Default on Null". This will ensure that when you are
   NOT passing any value for ID, the system generates next sequence
   number automatically.

**For solution 2:**

DDL Statement: **`ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1`**

Table Creation in SQL Developer:
[image: Table Creation in SQL Developer]